# How to get the value of an element into .html()

Tags: jquery, hex, rgb

I'm trying to convert a HEX color tot rgb. I got it working so far but now I want to get the value of an element into my html() function. This is what I got:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){

      function convertHex(hex,opacity){
        hex = hex.replace('#','');
        r = parseInt(hex.substring(0,2), 16);
        g = parseInt(hex.substring(2,4), 16);
        b = parseInt(hex.substring(4,6), 16);

        result = ' - rgb('+r+', '+g+', '+b+')';
        return result;
      }
      $('h1').html(convertHex('#000000'));

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="thecolor">#ef8605</span>
    <h1></h1>
```

Now the `#000000` should be replaced by the value of the `span` with `.thecolor` class.
Can someone help me out with how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a variable and use `.text()` to get the value

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

      function convertHex(hex,opacity){
        hex = hex.replace('#','');
        r = parseInt(hex.substring(0,2), 16);
        g = parseInt(hex.substring(2,4), 16);
        b = parseInt(hex.substring(4,6), 16);

        result = ' - rgb('+r+', '+g+', '+b+')';
        return result;
      }
      var hex = $('.thecolor').text();
      $('h1').html(convertHex(hex));

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="thecolor">#ef8605</span>
    <h1></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('.thecolor').html()` to get the value(s) of the element(s) having the class `thecolor`.

Note that using `$('.thecolor').html()` will get the html tags potentially included in the `<span></span>`. You can use instead `$('.thecolor').text()` to get the content **without** the inner html tags.

If you have many of them, you can use [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop them and [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add them to the destination

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    function convertHex(hex,opacity)
    {
        hex = hex.replace('#','');
        r = parseInt(hex.substring(0,2), 16);
        g = parseInt(hex.substring(2,4), 16);
        b = parseInt(hex.substring(4,6), 16);

        result = ' - rgb('+r+', '+g+', '+b+')';
        return result;
    }
    $('.thecolor').each(function()
    {
        $('h1').append(convertHex($(this).html()));
        // $('h1').append(convertHex($(this).text())); <-- or this one if you may have html tags in the containers $('h1')
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="thecolor">#ef8605</span>
<span class="thecolor">#ffffff</span>
<h1></h1>
```

Comment: You'd probably want `.text()` in this case rather than `.html()`.

Comment: @freedomn-m yep but an answer with `.text()` was submitted (I upvoted it) after I answered. `.html()` will work too if there is no html tags in the source

Comment: I think you answer is valid a separate answer as you've used `.each`